# How to Resolve 'Error while installing steem-python'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, steemit

I have a VM with Ubuntu 18.04.1.

`python3 --version` says 3.6.5.

I installed pip without any failure (seems like).
Then I tried to install steem-python with

```
pip install steem
```

but I get a failure, which looks like:

```
bla bla bla

...

^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

compilation terminated.

  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for scrypt

Running setup.py clean for scrypt

...

^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-0iqf8q/scrypt/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-1dMD0Y-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-0iqf8q/scrypt/
```

Now I'm out of ideas. Can anybody help me to fix this? How can I install it?

My goal is to interact with the steem blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install python3-dev on ubuntu (in addition to unixodbc-dev) and it did work.

Please ensure you've installed these:

$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev

$ sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev

FYI : Python 2.x users, will need python-dev instead.

Comment: No, i did so after your advice, but i have still the same failure, it seems like.

Comment: It seems you are missing the library for it. Please try to install it and have a check.